# How are trophies in Clash of Clans calculated?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've practically browsed the whole Internet, but didn't find any particular formula for calculating the trophy outcomes in a PvP game such as Clash of Clans. This is what I figured out so far:

- At some point I thought that the sum of points was always 48, and that it is separated between the winner and the loser, weighted in favor of the one with fewer points. This turned out to be not true, because I myself have been in battles where winning I got like 13 trophies and losing I got 14 (total 27).
- I thought it is some kind of an ELO rating system, but couldn't confirm it actually is, not just because there is no negative trophy count in CoC, but also because in small differences in rank you could actually gain a lot of trophies (like 30) when winning.
- As far as I know you're matched against opponents with a rank that is ranged within ~230 trophies compared to your rank
- Ps: *I'm not talking about clan trophies, but the trophies of a single person in normal multiplayer.*

I'd like to ask that if anyone more familiar with the subject brang more light into this, preferably a Supercell employee. ;)

Comment: I always thought it was based on the difference in trophies. Like you could steal a lot from someone who has way more than you. And basically none from someone who has less than you. Just my own experience, so not posting an answer.

Comment: this is true. However that doesn't say by what formula are they calculated

Comment: If they have less than you, you will just get less trophies, usually not 0 in a non-revenge attack. Just a side note you can get upto 60 trophies in a revenge attack and upto 34 in a non-revenge

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the Supercell Clash of Clans forums, zachUVA (a forum moderator) has posted a thread explaining the "math" behind the trophy calculations (the thread can be found here: http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/342724-TROPHY-OFFERS-Formulas-discovered%21%21).

His main point, quoted directly from the thread, is this: "SC’s consistent claims that matchmaking and trophy offers are purely based on the cup difference between the two players is fully supported by the data I gathered. TH level, experience level, base strength, and everything else had no impact on cup offers. There were also no inconsistencies in the data; every data point fit the general trend."

The formula he found with his research is the following equation where x is **your trophies minus your opponent's trophies** and y is **the number of trophies you can get for getting a 3 star victory**: y=-0.63599+(59.43467+0.63599)/(1+0.991798e^0.00576x)

Comment: these are very interesting resources. Wonder why I didn't find them by googling. Another interesting thing would be how SC came up with those formulas, but I will read that thread and hopefully will find out. Great answer!